# Can I use some method to get the variable name?

Tags: ios, instance, var

I creat a instance of a class. Can I use some method to get the variable name, then I print out it? I just want this when I do some test project. I think I really mean is the variable name.

Comment: What do you call "the instance name"?

Comment: @newXcoder What you want to say ?

Comment: You can save those parameters in an array and loop through it. I am not sure if there are any instance name fetching in iOS. If you are asking about this `const char* className = class_getName([yourObject class]);
NSLog(@"yourObject is a: %s", className);` try it.

Comment: just add this code in your header and use it anywhere : #define NSLogVariable(x) NSLog( @"Variable : %s = %@",#x,x)   define it as a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you can't.

Object instances don't have names. Classes have names. Methods have names. Properties have names. But object instances don't. Variables have names, but they're not unique to instances, and you don't have access to that programmatically, anyway.

If you just invoke the `description` method, you'll generally get a little something to identify the instance, but it's not a name.

`UIView` objects have a numeric `tag` property, so for those you can set that property and identify your controls that way.

Comment: thanks for this longer explaintion

Comment: "Variables have names" - I'd say variables *had* names until the code is piped through the compiler - the abstraction goes away then and they simply become relative stack addresses.

Answer (score 0):

property_getAttributes is part of the Objective-C runtime, as described here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH1-SW1.

If you want to gain some kind of introspection about ObjC classes, it is the way to go. I don't think this is unstable, since the Objective-C runtime itself is quite stable. Furthermore there is an official guide (see link above) so you can trust it to be as stable as any other official Apple API.